# How to add the canonical repository in ubuntu 16.04 ?

Tags: 16.04, apt, skype, repository, canonical

I have become paranoid with adding new repositories lately, but since I need skype, I have to add the repository called canonical.

I read, it is necessary to uncomment (delete the # sign at the beginning) the line in **/etc/apt/sources.list** for the repository I want to use.

However, when I am in /etc/apt/sources.list, I can't find any repository with **canonical** in its name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"canonical partners":

It is these 2 lines ...

```
$ grep partner sources.list
## 'partner' repository.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

or from the desktop (image shows `zesty` instead of `xenial`)...

[image]

Comment: many thanks, I must have deleted these lines accidently, can I just copy from your answer and paste it into sources.list without further change?

Comment: Yes sir/man. You can add those 2 lines, remove the # in front of the 2 lines and do an "update" of your sources.

Comment: do i have to apt-get update it or something else to take effect?

Comment: yes, use the gui version; it will prompt for it. commandline you need to do it yourself.